# pgf-umlcd operation command fails within a beamer document

Tags: beamer, pgf-umlcd

It appears there is some incompatibility with the zero option to specify a virtual operation in pgf-umlcd with beamer. It works fine in an article document.

The example pgf-umlcd code was taken directly from their documentation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{class}{ClassName}{0,0}
         \operation[0]{name ( parameters list ) : type of value returned}
      \end{class}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've tried various workarounds but this is beyond my ability to parse what is happening and where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to protect the `\textit` command which is used by that option. Somehow, it is fragile here.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\textit

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{class}{ClassName}{0,0}
        \operation[0]{name ( parameters list ) : type of value returned}
        \end{class}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]